# Big Interger in php Converts as Float

Tags: php, web-services

Hello i have tried to use a `Webservice`method that takes a parameter as a `big integer` which has `+25 digits`, however, when i use `var_dump` function, show the parameter as a `float`:

```
array (size=3)
  'recIds' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => float 5.66069912127E+18
  'username' => string 'username' (length=9)
  'password' => string 'password' (length=4)
```

Here is my .Php

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$sms_client = new SoapClient('http://87.107.121.54/post/send.asmx?wsdl', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

$parameters['recIds'] = array(5660699121269961781); //for Example
$parameters['username'] = "username";
$parameters['password'] = "password";

var_dump($parameters);
?>
```

I really need the parameter to be passed as integer

Comment: Assuming you're working with a 32-bit version of PHP, then yes, this will happen.... switch to a 64-bit version of PHP, which supports an integer range of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, or from −(2^63) to 2^63 − 1

Comment: @MarkBaker , Hey thank you, but I've downloaded 64-bit version of WAMP and ran it, however, still the same, is it possible that i am doing somehow wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit Goes to @MarkBaker

Assuming you're working with a 32-bit version of PHP, then yes, this will happen.... switch to a 64-bit version of PHP, which supports an integer range of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, or from −(2^63) to 2^63 − 1